# there a quick an easy way to remove commas from a flow screen number input component?

Tags: visual-workflow

I'm working on a screen flow. When I run the flow and write a number I get a comma in the thousands place. I was wondering if there is a quick an easy way to make sure the comma is removed? For example instead of 1,000 I would have 1000 when I run the flow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'Text' element of Flow screen instead of 'Number'.

Additionally, if you want only numbers to be entered and not text, you can add validation for the element to allow only numbers.

[image]

Comment: I suppose just `ISNUMBER({!yourField})` should be enough as validation formula